# Where to put *Footnote Text...Bottom of page or section?

Tags: usability, readability

I have a fairly long page that leads off with a bold statistic in the hero section of the page.  That statistic has an * that needs to be cited where that statistic came from.   Should the footnote portion of that come in the same section or at the bottom of the page? Shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's a third option: a **footnote popup**.

[image]

The physical location of a footnote is in relation to a printed page, in interactive texts, the footnote popup makes much more sense:

- The information is in the exact place where the footnote is
- You avoid having to look for a special place to put the information and help the reader not to browse looking for it

*Image from [pagetoscreen.net](http://www.pagetoscreen.net/journal/item/footnotes_endnotes_sidenotes_and_popup_notes)*

[Footnotes popup Codepen example](https://codepen.io/railaru/pen/rQJeYY)

Answer (score 0):

The bottom of the page.

Why?

- Stick with learned behavior. That's where readers are used to seeing footnotes.
- Users could miss them. If you put the footnotes below the section the text appears in, your users will not know exactly where to look per section.
- Potential Inconsistency. You'd also be setting a precedent to find footnotes throughout the page/site the same way and if you're not designing the entire site, there would be inconsistency.
- Easy to implement. If you have a dev team that can do a pop-up like the suggestion below, go for it! Otherwise, footnotes at the bottom would be your next best options.